# Synchronized functions in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

I have a class with a function which is synchronized like so:

```
public synchronized void enqueue(int number) {...}
```

In my program I have several threads running all wanting to use this function on a specific object of the class. What I would like to happen is for the threads to simply try using the function and if it is locked to not wait on it simply skip running that function.

Can this be done **without** using the Java.util.concurency library and only using syncronization primatives?

**The restriction of not using concurrency is not optional**

Comment: No, it isn't possible, you have to dig deeper and use the java.util.concurrent objects.

Comment: Why would you want to use only primitives instead of the constructs made to make this so much easier? :-)

Comment: @Maurício That's not true. You can do it, but the solution isn't pretty.

Comment: This is for a **university** project and this is one of the restrictions... I'm not happy about it either...

Comment: @glowcoder how is it possible? Either he is going to use the objects in there or wait/notify, which is the same. Is there any other option?

Comment: @Maurício wait/notify is not the same as java.util.concurrent...

Comment: @nayish If this is for a university project you should have been upfront about that, and tagged this as homework. I had an almost complete implementation done up thinking this was for a real life job...

Comment: sorry, I didn't know it made a difference... this is extra credit... whoever has the fastest program wins and this can definitely help me win....

Comment: well, if a method call is optional and you are interested in speed, i'd just skip calling the method all together.

Comment: It's not optional, it will get called later on, it's just optional for it to happen right away... but there is no need to worry about starvation since every thread will eventually get its turn using the function since they are all somewhat interlinked...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the AtomicInteger solution, but of course AtomicInteger is part of the concurrency package. You can follow the same principle (with lower efficiency, though) with the following simple code:

```
private boolean locked = false;

public void enqueue(int number) {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (locked) {
            return;
        }
        locked = true;
    }

    try {
        // Synchronized goodness goes here.
    } finally {
        synchronized (this) {
            locked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use any synchronization primitives I'd recommend using something like the [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) class to leverage a CAS (compare-and-swap) operation for your anti-concurrency strategy:

```
public void enqueue(int number) {
    if (!atomicInteger.compareAndSet(0, 1) {
        return;
    }

    try {
        // Synchronized goodness goes here.
    } finally {
        atomicInteger.set(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're restricted here, here's what I would do:

Make a class with the ability to tell it that you want to lock on it. There are two types of locks: passive lock, and active lock. A passive lock will allow an unlimited number of threads to pass. An active lock will make it belong only to that thread.

When you want a passive lock, you have to register yourself, and unregister yourself when you're done. You'll wait on an internal object until all active locks are done.

When you want an active lock, you wait for all current passive locks have unregistered. If there's currently an active lock (store a thread reference to see if there is, utilizing `Thread.currentThread()`) then wait until notified. You can then set yourself as the referred thread. When you unregister, if there are waiting active locks, notify one of them (consider a `Set<Thread>` to register this). If there aren't, notify all the passive locks that are waiting and they can go through.

There's going to be a lot of unanswered questions here, and I doubt it's perfect, but this is most of what you're looking for...

Answer (score 0):

May be you can you synchronize the object that handles the Queue. If someone else ois using the queue the enqueue does nothing. I have an example that compiles and run. Very simple example but not pretty:

```
    class Queue {
        public void enqueue(int number) {
            // something in this method for demo purposes only 
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){}
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" done");
        }
    }

    class Demo {
        private static Queue e = new Queue();

        public void enqueue(int number) {
            Queue q = getQueue();
            if (q!=null) {
                q.enqueue(number);
                releaseQueue(q);
            } else {
                // do nothing since the queue is being used
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" done doing nothing");
            }
        }

        public synchronized Queue getQueue() {
            Queue b = e;
            e = null;
            return b;
        }

        public synchronized void releaseQueue(Queue q) {
            e = q;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Demo d = new Demo();
                        d.enqueue(5);
                    }
                }, "Thread "+j);
                t.start();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e){}
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

**YES You can implement locking on your own by managing a static variable in that class, or a using a "lock" text file, for example.**

**HOWEVER** Although this simplistic hack would not be terribly difficult --- the java.util.concurrency  package solution would be EVEN EASIER, AND is a better choice because, as you will quickly find, when building multithreaded resources into applications our needs will quickly  exceed your current expectations

Don't worry about the WHOLE concurrency package -- I find that just taking 3 minutes to learn how to use the AtomicBoolean or AtomicLong fields can be enough to enable simple, multithreaded logic with a minimal effort.

Comment: once again.. the restriction is not my idea... I can't use the concurrency package and any further talk about how much more work this adds is definitely not making me fell any better with this horrible restriction given by my professor...

Comment: Man - Tough crowd :) ... reread the first part - I think it appplies